# VB help: Multiple textboxs display into single label in specific order

Tags: vb.net, textbox, label

I have a project that involves multiple textboxes and lables. In a tab there will 3 groupboxes (gb). gb1 will have radio buttons to select. gb2 will have some lables and 2 rows of textboxes. gb3 will have all labels that will modify based on user input from the textboxes in gb2. the labels and textboxes in gp2 will be arranged in rows and columns and created at runtime with selection of radiobutton2.

What i am trying to accomplish is have data from a row of labels and the two rows of 8 textboxes within gb2 dislpay into three labels within gb3 in order from left to right based on the bottom textbox having a text length of 5 and textchanged event handler. Note that not all boxes will need to be filled.

For example say the two textboxes below column 1 and column 4 have user input. I would like two separate labels in gb3 to display that user input in order with column 1 first and column 4 second.

How would one go about this **without** building a truck load of if and then statements?

e.g.

```
if textbox9.textlength = 5 and textbox12.textlength = 5 then
    label17.text= textbox1.text & "  " & textbox4.text 
    label18.text= textbox9.text & "  " & textbox12.text
end if
```

Too many combinations of user inputs for all 8 column of textboxes to encode. Looking for a smarter solution.

Maybe this will help 
[image]

Comment: Hi! Perhaps a screenshot of your form? so we can understand how we can help you more.

Comment: also, perhaps creating a subroutine and passing these textboxes as arguments will help a lot. have you tried that?

Comment: I will as soon as I get enough rep points to do so.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are referring to.  I'm fairly new to programming.

Comment: my apologies, I forgot about that (screenshots need rep).

Comment: No problem, I tried to explain the layout as best i could... but a picture would be so much better.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps creating a subroutine might help, friend.

subroutines are groups of code that run a certain task when you call it and provide proper arguments to it.

In lieu of the example given, perhaps the following can help you

```
     Public Sub ManipulateLables(ByVal FirstTextToCheck as Textbox, _
      ByVal SecondTextToCheck as Textbox, _
      ByVal FirstLabel as Label, _
      ByVal SecondLabel as Label, _
      ByVal FirstText as Textbox, _
      ByVal SecondText as Textbox, _
      ByVal ThirdText as Textbox, _
      ByVal FourthText as Textbox)


           If FirstTextToCheck.textlength = 5 and SecondTextToCheck.textlength = 5 then
                FirstLabel.text= FirstText.text & "  " & SecondText.text 
                SecondLabel.text= ThirdText.text & "  " & FourthText.text
           End If

     End Sub
```

Now, you can call them via a subroutine tied to an event handler
example: in a button press:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ManipulateLabels(textbox9, textbox12, label17,label18, textbox1, textbox4, textbox9, textbox12)
    End Sub
```

What happened here is that we called the ManipulateLabels subroutine, and passed the controls we would like to be affected by the subroutine as Arguments.

FirstToCheck in the subroutine now becomes Textbox9, SecondToCheck becomes textbox12, and so on.

Let us know if this has helped you.

Comment: Forgive me but i am not seeing how the code above will be able tell which of the textboxes have user input and then put it in the proper order(left most first right most last). In my example in the first post i list column 1 and 4 but it could be any combination of the 8 columns. fyi each column has a defining label and then two texboxes.

Comment: Try mastering subroutines. I get the feeling it's the only thing you have lacking in friend. [Click Here](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/nets9p2.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your requirement entirely. But here is an example, built on my own requirement hope not too far from yours. In this example I have 4 TextBoxes, 1 Label and 1 Button declared in designer. What the application do:

1. On Form Load, add all textboxes to a List of TextBox variable.
2. On Button click, iterate through the list of textbox which text is not empty based on TextBox's name order, get the text append it to Label separated by space.

---

Screenshot after Button1 clicked:
[image]

TextBox name (left to right): TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, TextBox4

---

Code snippet:

```
Dim TextBoxes As List(Of TextBox)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TextBoxes = New List(Of TextBox)()
    For Each control As Control In TabPage1.Controls.Cast(Of Control).Where(Function(x) TypeOf x Is TextBox)
        TextBoxes.Add(control)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Label1.Text = ""
    For Each textBox As TextBox In TextBoxes.Where(Function(x) x.Text.Length > 0).OrderBy(Function(x) CInt(x.Replace("TextBox", "")))
        Label1.Text &= textBox.Text & " "
    Next
End Sub
```

Since the TextBox is created from code in your case, then you can just add the TextBox to list after it created. I hope you get the idea and further hope the concept applicable in your situation.

Comment: I think this is a step in the right direction.  I have two rows of text boxes that I need to keep separate.  Also two more text boxes above the rows that need to be separated from the function.

Comment: Really wish I could post images.  It would make explaining this so much easier.

Comment: With this I thought about creating a new group box at runtime with my 8 textboxes so that I can keep things organized the way I want. Worked fine for the first entry but when the user puts a second entry it copys over the first entry several times before displaying the second.

Comment: @Nightmistx22 you can upload screenshot somewhere (imgur for example), and share the link here. I can edit your post to embed the screenshot image later if it relevant.

Comment: If I don't misunderstand the problem, maybe you forgot to reset the label, so it keep appending existing text with newly typed entries. maybe.

Comment: @Nightmistx22 updated my code to fix ordering. The textbox will now ordered by number after "TextBox" string, check if it can solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you name the textboxes in order, in the format of Name-col,row, you can flatten them into a list and check if any have text and join them together with a space between.   This gives you the advantage of getting the col,row position of the textbox from the name. Something like this would work, I used "Input" for the name of the textbox:

```
    'This uses linq to flatten the result to an array, then join is used to create _
     a string with spaces between
    label1.Text = Join(gb2.Controls _
                        .OfType(Of TextBox)() _
                        .Where(Function(w) w.Name.Contains("Input") AndAlso Not w.Text = "") _
                        .OrderBy(Function(t) t.Name).ToArray, " ")

    label1.Text = String.Join(" ", gb2.Controls _
                        .OfType(Of TextBox)() _
                        .Where(Function(w) w.Name.Contains("Input") AndAlso Not w.Text = "") _
                        .OrderBy(Function(t) t.Name))
```

You may have to `Imports System.Linq` if you're using an older version of VS

Comment: Gave this a try using a textchange event handle. Came back with argument 'source array' cannot be converted to type 'string'.

Comment: Did you type it in or copy and paste?  The `Join` statement wrapping the whole thing is important.

Comment: Copy & paste modifying as needed.

Comment: Did you use `Join`? or `String.Join`?  `String.Join` has the parameters reversed.

Comment: Yes. I copied your code above and just changed the label name, the groupbox name and the "input" name to match the names of the controls in my form.

Comment: I suspect, for some reason your VS is forcing you to use `String.Join`.  Just change the order of the parameters, put the space in quotes first then the linq expression. And drop the ToArray at the end